# Request does not work on live host, but does work locally

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to get records from a server using PHP. When I run the code below using XAMPP, it works without any issue. However, when I upload the code to my web host (infinityfree), the request no longer works. The error I receive is `Server is offline`.

Please see my code below:

```
try
{
    $rQuery = new QueryServer( $serverIP, $serverPort );

    $aInformation = $rQuery->GetInfo( );
    $aServerRules = $rQuery->GetRules( );
    $aBasicPlayer = $rQuery->GetPlayers( );
    $aTotalPlayers = $rQuery->GetDetailedPlayers( );

    $rQuery->Close( );
}
catch (QueryServerException $pError)
{
    echo 'Server is offline';
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you include the file that has the QueryServer  class?

Comment: We would need to know `class QueryServer` to be able to answer the question. Most likely it depends on php modules that are not available on the hosted server. Maybe also a resource required by that class can't be reached from that host.